# MongoDB BSON file storage with MongoEngine possible?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoengine

I'm using the MongoEngine driver to define and connect to my MongoDB instance and I now want to use a BSON field to store a file. When I used GridFS for storing my files, I used the MongoEngine [FileField](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.FileField) like this:

```
class UserFile(Document):
    filename = StringField()
    file_data = FileField()
```

I now want to store the files as BSON, but I can't find any "BsonField" in the [MongoEngine list of field types](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#fields). Does anybody know how I can store a file as BSON with the MongoEngine driver? All tips are welcome!

Comment: No idea what you are talking about. Please express your problem in plain terms because the ones you are using do not suit any valid solution.

Comment: @NeilLunn - Hmmm, then I must be understanding BSON wrongly. The thing is that I currently store files in MongDB using the GridFS field. But since I will never have documents larger than 16MB, I don't want to use GridFS anymore (because it divides the file into chunks, which I don't want). Maybe the correct question would in this case be: would you have an example of how I can store files in MongoDB without using GridFS?

Comment: Umm, all MongoDB storage is BSON. So if your content is under 16MB in the document as a whole then just store the value in a "field/property". SQL RDBMS people call them "blobs". MongoDB does not care. Data is data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You meant this:

```
class UserFile(Document):
    filename = StringField()
    file_data = BinaryField()
```

MongoDB will store **anything** as long as the whole document is under the 16MB limit. It's the MongoDB equivalent to a "blob" in SQL RDBMS terms.

For mongoengine [`BinaryField`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.BinaryField) denotes this as that kind of "raw" storage type. So rather than "marshall out" to a GridFS collection, the data is "embedded" within the document. The same 16MB limit to the document applies, but MongoDB has no problem with this. GridFS is in fact a mechanism to store data beyond the 16MB limit. Nothing more, just driver code to split the data into document "chunks".

Don't expect to "query" into the content of a BinaryField, much the same as the limitations on GridFS storage.